# The app is working on my phone but not any other device

Tags: ios, swift

I tried to solve this problem for a couple of days before submitting the app, so here it goes. I am developing an app that uses UserDefaults to save a string from a different view controller with a press of a button and to transfer it a table view in the next view controller. However, for some unknown reason, the app works perfectly on iPhone X (and iPhone XR), but it does not save the string and react to a press of a button whenever I run the app on a different iPhone model. Here is my code:

//FirstViewController

```
@IBAction func buttonIsPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if var items = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "items") as? [String]{
        var newitems = textField.text!.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet(charactersIn: ",  []()\n.:"))
        print(items)
        if newitems.contains(""){
            newitems.removeAll { $0 == ""}
            items.append(contentsOf: newitems)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(items, forKey: "items")
        }else{
            let newitems = textField.text!.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet(charactersIn: ",  []()\n.:"))
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newitems, forKey: "items")
        }

        textField.text = ""

        }
}
```

//SecondViewController

```
var scannedText: String = "Detected text can be edited here." {
    didSet {
        textView.text = scannedText
        let str = scannedText.uppercased()
        let allergens = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "items") as! [String]
        let string = str.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet(charactersIn: ", []()\n.:"))
        print(string)
        for allergen in allergens{
            if string.contains(String(Substring(allergen))) == true {
                print("I found the string \(allergen)")
                allegenLabel.text = "Not safe"
                allegenLabel.alpha = 1  //Make the label visible
                allegenLabel.textColor = .red

                // let attributedString = allergen.highlight([allergen], this: .red)
                // textView.attributedText = attributedString
                allergensFound.append(allergen)
                print(allergensFound)

            }
            if string.contains(String(Substring(allergen))) == false {
                allegenLabel.text = "Safe"
                allegenLabel.alpha = 1 //Make the label visible
                allegenLabel.textColor = UIColor.colorGreen
                //                    table.reloadData()
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Please ask me if you need further description in the code. Thanks!

Edit: To be more exact I am creating a code that will find a string in the array of strings that will then notify the user with AllegenLabel.text. The whole app is divided into different view controllers. The user inputs in a string using a text field in FirstViewController and then that string has to be found in a different array of strings in SecondViewController. For some reason UserDefaults successfully stores and retrieves the string on my phone but does not work on different devices. For example, whenever I click the save button in FirstViewController, a string has to be stored and shown in the console, but for some unknown reason it does not work. Sorry if I was unclear

Comment: Please be clearer about what you (the user) do and what happens or doesn't happen as a result.

Comment: To be more exact I am creating a code that will find a string in the array of strings that will then notify the user with AllegenLabel.text. The whole app is divided into different view controllers. The user inputs in a string using a text field in FirstViewController and then that string has to be found in a different array of strings in SecondViewControl. Whenever I click the save button in FirstViewController, a string has to be stored and shown in the console, but for some unknown reason it does not work on the other devices, but it does work on my phone. Sorry if I was unclear

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try:

```
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

maybe...